# Create new forms programmatically from for function

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to create a new form for each article counted in my variable `articleQuantity`.

Obviously this does not work because I need to increment by 1 the form name at each loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < articleQuantity; i++)
{
    Form1 myForm1 = new Form1();
    myForm1.Show();
}
```

How can I achieve to create n forms named myForm1, myForm2, and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You want to access them after creating, create a public list like this

```
List<Form1> forms = new List<Form1>();
```

and then for creating code ;

```
for (int i = 0; i < articleQuantity; i++)
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    forms.Add(form);
    form.Show();
}
```

and for accessing them;

```
forms[index].DoWhatYouWant();
```

Answer (score 0):

> because I need to increment by 1 the form name at each loop

So you have many differents forms, one for each article? Why not having only one generic form which can show any kind of article, like this:

```
public partial class FormArticle {
    public FormArticle(Article a) { .... }
}
```

At this point, you can create multiple forms just like the other answers show.